# adding and removing item from a dropdown list when checking and unchecking checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html

I have 8 checkboxes currently on a page; each one represents an environment name. I pass the environment name into the code which then looks up a list of servers and populates those into a dropdown list with headings using optgroup.

A user can check a box and a set of server names are added to the dropdown. If, however, they uncheck the same box it's adding all the servers again to the dropdown. What I would like it to do is if a user unchecks a checkbox they have mistakenly checked I want the associated servers and optgroup heading removed from the dropdown.

Code so far:

```
serverList["BERT"] = ["server22", "server1", "server2", "server3"];
serverList["BOB"] = ["server10", "server55", "server99"];

function createServerList(env) {

    if (env != "") {

        if (! serverList[env]) {
            fadeInfoText("ERROR! No Lookup for " + env);
            return;
        }

        $("#ss1").append("<optgroup label='" + env + " Server List'>");

        for (var j = 0; j < serverList[env].length; j ++) {
            serveritem = serverList[env][j]
            $("#ss1").find("optgroup").append("<option value='" + serveritem + "'>" + serveritem + "</option>");
        }

        $("#ss1").multiselect('refresh');
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is missing important information like where `createServerList(env)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track and the code you have, works well to add the options to the select.

However, you could make it simpler and add `id` to the `optgroup`s that you are adding. This will in turn make it easy to remove the options when the checkbox is unchecked. All you will then need to do is to remove the appropriate `optgroup` based on the `id`.

This snippet will help you understand that:

```js
var serverList = {};
serverList["BERT"] = ["server22", "server1", "server2", "server3"];
serverList["BOB"] = ["server10", "server55", "server99"];

$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    refreshList(this.checked, this.value); // bind change event and call your routine
});

function refreshList(add, env) {
    if (! add) { // if checkbox is not checked...remove the optgroup..
        $("#ss1").find("optgroup#" + env).remove(); // ..based on id as the checkbox value
        return; // we don't need to continue
    }
    // if checkbox is checked..  
    var $optgrp = $("<optgroup>"); // ..add an optgroup..
    $optgrp.attr("id", env);       // ..with id as the checkbox value..
    $optgrp.attr("label", env);    // .. and whatever label   
    serverList[env].forEach(function(item, idx) { // iterate your serverlist
        var $opt = $("<option>");  // add an option
        $opt.val(item);            // add server name to its value..
        $opt.text(item);           // .. and text
        $opt.appendTo($optgrp);    // append it to the optgroup created earlier
    });
    $optgrp.appendTo("#ss1");      // append the optgroup to the select element
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" value="BERT" />
<input id="c2" type="checkbox" value="BOB" />
<hr />
<select id="ss1"></select>
```

Here is a fiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/bkv1gh6m/

.

Comment: many thanks for the information, little confused with this part

$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    refreshList(this.checked, this.value); // bind change event and call your routine
});


how do i call this i have tried wrapping this in a function which i an calling from my onclick within the html but didnt work.

Comment: @mithandra: the `on` method is binding the `change` event on all `input`s which are of the type `checkbox`. The anonymous function is passed as a parameter which gets called whenever the checkbox state is changed. Inside this anonymous function we are calling our `refreshList‘ function. This function takes the parameters as the state and the value of the current checkbox. You can understand the rest from here.

Comment: @mithandra: do not call `onclick` from html markup. It is bad practice. Use the jQuery `on` method to unobtrusively add event listeners.