# if checkbox checked change the select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I would like to generate selects options depends on checkbox. Like I have checkbox with 3 values: Film, Videoclip, Serial and `<select>` form. When I click "Film" I would like to have `<select>` with option: Comedy, Horror & when I "Videoclip" `<select>` will change values to: Hip-Hop, Pop.

I'm trying for a few hours with javascript & jquery but still nothing :/

Comment: add proper event listener to the checkboxes. Then, show desired select element depending on the value of the selected checkbox. Anyway, it would be easier to help you if you provided code snippets.

Comment: would be good to have your code

Comment: This might help you -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/27621468/1355315

Comment: Are you really looking for a client-side only solution?

Comment: thank you all for quick answers & solution. I will try to implement on my site. "Are you really looking for a client-side only solution?" - No, select options will be downloaded from mysql database, but I think I will manage to do it on my own.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try using jQuery and events something like this?

```js
$(function () {
  var checked = ["Check 1", "Check 2", "Check 3"];
  var unchecked = ["Uncheck 1", "Uncheck 2", "Uncheck 3"];
  function updateSelect (arr) {
    $("select").html("");
    $.each(arr, function (i, v) {
      $("select").append('<option value="' + v + '">' + v + '</option>');
    });
  }
  updateSelect (unchecked);
  $("#check").change(function () {
    if (this.checked)
      updateSelect(checked);
    else
      updateSelect(unchecked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="check" /> Check</label><br />
<select></select>
```

Your snippet is now ready. Have a look:

```js
$(function () {
  var iFilm = ["Comedy", "Horror", "Sci-Fi"];
  var iVideoClip = ["Hip-Hop", "Pop", "Rap"];
  var iSerial = ["Serial 1", "Serial 2", "Serial 3"];
  $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    $("select").html("");
    $("input:checked").each(function () {
      addItemsFromArray(eval("i" + this.id));
    });
  });
  function addItemsFromArray (arr) {
    $.each(arr, function (i, v) {
      $("select").append('<option value="' + v + '">' + v + '</option>');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Film" /> Film</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" id="VideoClip" /> VideoClip</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Serial" /> Serial</label><br />
<select></select>
```

**Note:** I have used `eval`, which is strongly discouraged. Without using `eval`, the other part is using `data-*` attributes.

```js
$(function () {
  var data = {};
  data.iFilm = ["Comedy", "Horror", "Sci-Fi"];
  data.iVideoClip = ["Hip-Hop", "Pop", "Rap"];
  data.iSerial = ["Serial 1", "Serial 2", "Serial 3"];
  $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    $("select").html("");
    $("input:checked").each(function () {
      addItemsFromArray(data[$(this).attr("data-content")]);
    });
  });
  function addItemsFromArray (arr) {
    $.each(arr, function (i, v) {
      $("select").append('<option value="' + v + '">' + v + '</option>');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Film" data-content="iFilm" /> Film</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" id="VideoClip" data-content="iVideoClip" /> VideoClip</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" id="Serial" data-content="iSerial" /> Serial</label><br />
<select></select>
```

On a different note, if you wanna make only one option selectable at a time, feel free to change from `type="checkbox"` to `type="radio"` and give the same name.

Answer (score 0):

From your questions, I assume you have 3 checkbox with different value for each. If your application only allows 1 option, why dont use radio button instead?

Aside from that, it is actually quite easy. Just put the "onchange" event listener on your checkbox and then populate your `<select>` tag (whether using pre-written variable or ajax)

simple example in vanilla js

```
<input type="checkbox" value="film" id="film">
<select id="someDropdown"></select>

<script>
    var film = document.getElementById("film");
    film.addEventListener("change", function(){
        // populate the dropdown list
        var options = "<option>Comedy</option>" + "<option>Horror</option>"
        document.getElementById("someDropdown").innerHTML = options;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sure radio button instead will be better

Comment: Your solution seems to be the simplest one. But it dosen't work on my test site. 
`<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var film = document.getElementById("film");
        film.addEventListener("change", function(){
        // populate the dropdown list
        var options = "<option>Comedy</option>" + "<option>Horror</option>";
        document.getElementById("someDropdown").innerHTML = options;
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" value="film" id="film">
<select id="someDropdown"></select>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: you can not put the script on `<head>` tag as browser reads html from top to bottom and at the time it parses `document.getElementById("film")`, there is no DOM with id="film" yet. Try put it just before the closing `</body>` tag and see if it works

Comment: what a simple mistake :p Thanks a lot Joshua!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var filmValues = {
    comedy: 'Comedy',
    horror: 'Horror'
}

$('#filmCb').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $.each(filmValues, function (key, value) {
            $('#filmSelect')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", key)
                .text(value));
        });
    } else {
        $('#filmSelect').empty()
    }
});
```

The html:

```
<form action="">
    <input id="filmCb" type="checkbox" name="param" value="film">Film
    <select id="filmSelect"></select>
    <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php // Genre 

$query  = "SELECT genre_pl FROM genre WHERE is_movie = 1 ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
// Test if there was a query error
confirm_query($result); ?>
<script> var options_film = ""; </script>
    <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
      ?>
    <pre> <?php var_dump($row) ?> </pre>
    <script> options_film += "<option>" + <?php echo json_encode($row); ?> +     "</option>"; </script>
           <?php } ?>

<?php mysqli_free_result($result); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var film = document.getElementById("film");
    film.addEventListener("change", function(){
    // populate the dropdown list
    document.getElementById("someDropdown").innerHTML = options_film;
});
```

It works! But I feel it's sloppy programming. It is okay to mix javascript with php just like that?

Answer (score 0):

here is a small bit of code to make each checkbox selected individually.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Film").click(function(){
   `$("#Film").prop("checked", false);
});
$("#VideoClip").click(function(){
    `$("#VideoClip").prop("checked", false);
});
$("#Serial").click(function(){
    `$("#Serial").prop("checked", false);
});
});
```

And the HTML :

```
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="Film" data-content="iFilm" /> Film</label><br />
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="VideoClip" data-content="iVideoClip" /> 
 VideoClip</label><br />
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="Serial" data-content="iSerial" /> Serial</label> 
 <br 
 />
```